# Android crash because of simple byte to String operation

Tags: android

Why does the following code make my Android App crashing?

```
new String("é".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "UTF8")
```

or simply

```
new String("é".getBytes())
```

How to do this?

Some infos:

- "é" is byte (195 169) is (U+00E9) (Found here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec)
- byte in java is always signed, so (195 169) is (-61 -87) (Info: [Convert unsigned byte to signed byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966580/convert-unsigned-byte-to-signed-byte))
- I am using Android 6.0.1 CM 13.0-20160813 NIGHTLY on my OnePlus One. It crashed instantly. Even if I enter it in the Android Studio debugger.
- It does not work if I use "StandardCharsets.UTF_8"

Error:

> 08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
>   08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego W/google-breakpad: 4.2.8
>   08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego W/google-breakpad: 70
>   08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   08-18 20:30:04.877 18914-18924/com.nextwebart.senego A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x5 in tid 18924 (JDWP)

Related question found here: [Java Strings Character Encoding - For French - Dutch Locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500529/java-strings-character-encoding-for-french-dutch-locales)

**------- EDIT:**

It happens only in my Android Studio debugger! So when I use this as watch or "evaluate expression". But when I do this in the code and then Log.d(...) it works fine!!!
Android Studio 2.1.3

I created an Android Studio Issue for that: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220366

Comment: please provide more specific logs

Comment: That's all what I have after executing this...

Comment: have you tried another device?

Comment: It looks for me like platform specific error. Does the app behave the same on emulator?

Comment: Yes, I have it also in my emulator. Nexus 6P API 23 Android 6.0 x86 ---------- Oh interesting! It happens only in my Android Studio debugger! So when I use this as watch or "evaluate expression". But when I do this in the code and then Log.d(...) it works fine!!!

Comment: What if you use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` too instead of "UTF8"? AFAIK, "UTF-8" is the right name of it

Comment: @Sergey Glotov: It's the same result. Crash. Even "new String("é".getBytes())" does not work. But only in Android Studio! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025153/android-crash-because-of-simple-byte-to-string-operation#comment65402397_39025153

Answer (score 0):

```
new String("é".getBytes())
```

It works perfectly for me. I have tested it with android min API 14.
Please check, it may occur for any other issue.

Comment: I am using Android 6.0.1 CM 13.0-20160813 NIGHTLY on my OnePlus One. It crashed instantly. Even if I enter it in the Android Studio debugger.

MinAPI is set to 10.